# Rounded corners on images

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/48Y37/

I want rounded corners on both corners at the top of the image. It technically is there but is being covered by the image. I've looked all over the web and I've seen people talk about `overflow: hidden;` or even JavaScript (which I want to avoid as much as possible) but I never seemed to be able to implement it onto my existing piece of code.

Thanks in advance.

```
<section class="container">
    <header>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CpL8u.png" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;" />
    </header>
    <section class="body">
        Lorem ipsum blahblah I don't know the rest.
    </section>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
header {
    width: 640px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
section.container {
    background: #fff;
    width: 620px;
    margin: auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #888;
}
section.body {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: You could provide a valid img. BTW it's an terribly annoying bug in **Chrome** that does not round images inside 'rounded' containers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry, an friend of mine has yet to create a header for me.

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden;` to `section.container`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add a `border-radius` to that image: http://jsfiddle.net/WouterJ/48Y37/1/

Answer (score 10):

To round the actual image, you have to make sure that the `<img>` tag's class actually has the `border-radius` property. For example:

```
<img class="roundrect" src="/whatever-your-source-is.png">
```

And the corresponding CSS would look like this:

```
.roundrect {
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Copy the picture with Snipping Tool and paste into *Paint*.
2. Choose the Rounded Rectangle shape and change the color to **white**.
3. Choose the largest size for the Rectangle.
4. Then put the white rounded border around the picture.
5. Then **copy** and **paste** the rounded picture wherever you need it.

Comment: Woah, 1998!! :)